# Dictionary key error on last word

Tags: python-2.7

I want to add all the words in a text file to a dictionary but only once(no repeats)and the rest of the words into a list.  I have figured out how to do so by looking at the answers.  This is what my code looked like when I gave up.  When i run it on a text file i get a keyerror on the last word in the file.  This way is pretty close to what the solution was but i could not get it to run properly and I do not understand why.  Will someone please try to explain this to me so I may have a better understanding.  Thank you.

```
import sys

def dictionary(filename):
  dict = {} 
  list = []
  open_file = open(filename, 'rU')
  for lines in open_file:
    line = lines.split()
    for words in line:
      word = words.lower()
    if not word in dict:
      dict[word]
    else:
      list.append(word)
  print (dict)

filename = sys.argv[1]

dictionary(filename)
```

Comment: There are several things wrong with your code, but this is not the right place for this type of question.  This question should be moved to [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I think you want your `if` to be *inside* the `for` loop. What is the point of `list`?  And once you establish that `word` isn't a key of `dict`, why then do you ask for the value at that key (`dict[word]`)?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a KeyError because you are not assigning a value to the key in the dictionary. Dictionaries in Python are best thought of as unordered sets of key/value pairs. See documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

You can fix your error by assigning dict[word] a value such as word:

```
dict[word] = word
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, it seems that what you actually want is a [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) ("A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects"). (Please comment on my answer if my assumption is wrong.)

```
from sys import argv

def dictionary(filename):
    words = set()
    repeats = []
    with open(filename, 'rU') as open_file:
        for line in open_file:
            for word in line.split():
                word = word.lower()
                if word in words:
                    repeats.append(word)
                words.add(word)
    return words

print dictionary(argv[1])
```

There were a couple of problems with your code. To begin with, the `KeyError` was being raised because you never assigned values to the items in your dictionary. (I suspect this was because there actually weren't any values to match up with keys, but you used a dictionary because there cannot be repeat keys in a dictionary.) The second problem was the indentation of your `if... else` statement. My final change was the use of the `with... as` construct to open the file, which has numerous benefits (such as closing the file even if there is an exception). I hope I interpreted your question properly and this answer is helpful to you.